# Smith form for a matrix

Tags: matrices, combinatorial-group-theory

I have a problem in progressing in SNF

We have matrix $A$:

$$A= 
\begin{bmatrix}
14&3&11\\8&-3&11\\3&3&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I tried to make the first row zeros except the first one and the same for the first column

I got the following matrix 
$$ A= 
\begin{bmatrix}
3&14&11\\0&22&22\\0&-11&-11
\end{bmatrix}
$$
  Then I stuck here

$$ A= 
\begin{bmatrix}
3&0&0\\0&0&33\\0&0&-11
\end{bmatrix}
$$
 The problem is that 3 don't divide all the entries so from here what shall I do . This happens alot to me so I would like to know what shal I do in such situation I don't want an alternative solution .

Answer (score 1):

From the last matrix $A$ (why are they all called $A\ \ddot\frown$?)
add row $3$ to row $1$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
3&0&-11\\0&0&33\\0&0&-11
\end{bmatrix},$$
then add four times column $1$ to column $4$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
3&0&1\\0&0&33\\0&0&-11
\end{bmatrix},$$
then swap columns $1$ and $3$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&3\\33&0&0\\-11&0&0
\end{bmatrix},$$
etc.

Comment: But what is theidea what exactly should be done in a general situation @lord Shark the Unknown